# Selecting a random row where a field is not equal to and another field is not in another table

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables. In tableA i store a file name in one of the columns. 
I also store that file name in tableB. The files are uploaded by logged users and their name is stored in tableA. What i actually want to do is to select a random row from tableA where the file name is not in tableB and additionally select from tableA only the rows that doesn't have the username of the logged user.

i have this code below that works but i can't figure out how to make it to exclude from results the rows that have the username of the logged user:

```
$sql = "SELECT columnA FROM TableA LEFT JOIN tableB on TableA.columnA = tableB.columnB 
WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

I tried adding after IS NULL **AND username != $loggeduser** (where is holding the logged user name) but it doesn't work.

Also i have read up that ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 will be very slow if there are many rows. Is it possible to improve my select code for that case too?

many thanks:)

Comment: Does not work is not an exact description of an error. Pls provide us with exact error message or detailed description of the unexpected behaviour. If username field is a varchar, then you would have to enclose $loggeduser by single quotes.

Comment: yes thank you very much that was exactly the mistake. i forgot the single quotes. Should i change the order by rand() Limit 1 or improve it if the table has many rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate the $loggedUser within the sql statement by single quotes ('), since it is a string:

```
$sql = "SELECT columnA FROM TableA LEFT JOIN tableB on TableA.columnA = tableB.columnB WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL AND username != '$loggeduser' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Hope, that you properly escape the contents of $loggedUser before using it in an sql statement with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (or other similar function / method available in the module you use to conect to the mysql server).

You are also right that the order by rand() limit 1 scales badly. I would replace this with a 3 step approach:

1. Obtain the number of records matching your criteria (tableB.columnB IS NULL AND username != '$loggeduser') using the count() sql function.
2. Generate a random number in php between 0 and the number obtained in step one -1.
3. Select a random record by using the above random number in the limit clause of a query that includes your original selection criteria again: select ... where tableB.columnB IS NULL AND username != '$loggeduser' limit $randomNumber, 1

Comment: Sorry but i am pretty new to coding so what do you mean by escape the contents?
I am using an include php file that is checking login user and set cookies. So by including it i always get the correct logged user i suppose.
how do i do the 3 step? The limit $randomNumber will be a number right? Is this correct: "Select columnA FROM TableA limit $randomNumber, 1";

Comment: Thank you! I did a $min and $max where i stored the total count. Problem was that i couldn't get the number with PHP but i found out to do "Select Count() AS" and now it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: I suggested to use the count() sql function. I never suggested to determine your population from php.

Comment: I did this:
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(columnA) AS total FROM TableA LEFT JOIN tableB on TableA.columnA = tableB.columnB 
WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL AND TableA.username = '$loggeduser'";
This give me the results but it's not what you suggested? because when i used without AS i couldn't get a number.
Thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnA FROM TableA LEFT JOIN tableB on TableA.columnA = tableB.columnB 
WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL AND username != loggedUser ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: pls accept it as the right answer then =] Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you should try this -

```
$sql = "SELECT columnA FROM TableA LEFT JOIN tableB on TableA.columnA = tableB.columnB 
WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL AND TableA.username != $loggedUser ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Explain your answer please